# mxttolbox SPF check - showing - all fail & Rest  ptr  a mx are Passed . What is the reason

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, spf

Newly created spf record for one of our domain . texxxxx.com

goes like this

> teXXXXXX.com  v=spf1 a mx ptr ip4:189.123.111.000 mx:teXXXXX.com -all ( not real values)

and mxtool spf check proviede following result

> - a    Pass   Match if IP has a DNS 'A' record in given domain
> - mx   Pass   Match if IP is one of the MX hosts for given domain name
> - ptr     Pass    Match if IP has a DNS 'PTR' record within given domain
> - ip4 189.123.111.000     Pass    Match if IP is in the given range
> - mx  texxxxxx.com    Pass    Match if IP is one of the MX hosts for given domain name
>
> **-   all     Fail    Always matches. It goes at the end of your record.**

I dont know why the last line result for -all failing is it the issue to concern ??

Answer (score 3):

SPF is checked in order. If the ip address of teXXXXXX.com matches the ip address of the connecting mail server, SPF passes, and it stops evaluating. It will only give a fail/negative result if none of the previous entries didn't pass. That is what -all means.

Comment: is this thing to worry because some suggest to use ~all instead of -all .. what s your suggestion  . and what you said is true .. then you can see my all previous records are passed then how come this -all failed .

Comment: It's not failing the SPF checking tool - it's designating that addresses other than the ones you're specifying should fail the SPF check.  That's exactly as it should be - the reason that you have SPF is to make checks fail for unauthorized addresses.

Comment: @Shane Madden  is this mean that SPF record is perfect for My Domain . and is this what should be for Ideal Scenario for Single Domain mail server . because  google apps prefers ~all instead of -all . is this makes difference to my mail server security

Comment: @panindra Regarding fail versus softfail, please see [here](http://serverfault.com/a/355513/72586). You haven't provided enough information to tell whether it's appropriate for your domain.  The idea is that you need to specify all servers that are authorized to send mail - have you done that?

Comment: @shane Madden  we are using only one domain  & single IP for this mail server to send mail  , is it required go for soft fail , unless some unautorized mails from spammers hijacking, we are sure that we only going to use this sane Ip Send mail.

Comment: @ShaneMadden I prefer not allow any other server than my current  Mail server configured to send mail from my static IP  for MY DOmain . so used -all (fail) is this assures that Spammers are less chance to hijack my mail server to send Spams ??

Comment: Yes, that's correct - if you're certain that only your allowed server should be sending mail, then `-all` tells recipient servers more emphatically than `~all` to reject mail from other servers.